# Executable fails to open files when double clicked

Tags: c, macos

I have a C file called fileTest.c, which simply contains this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    FILE* file =  fopen("test.txt","r");
    if (file == NULL) {
        printf("file failed to open\n");
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

In the same directory, I have the test.txt file, which is empty.
I compile like so: `gcc -Wall -std=gnu99 fileTest.c -o fileTest`
Everything works perfectly (nothing is printed) if I run the resultant executable in the command line with ./fileTest, but when I try to run the executable by double clicking the exec file, I get "file failed to open". I'm using macOS High Sierra 10.13.3. Why is this happening?

Comment: Likely because the double-click executed the program as if it was in a different folder/directory.  Add code to, on error, print the _current working directory_.

Comment: @chux How can I tell where it's running and/or explicitly state where it should be running or where it should be looking for files?

Comment: have you set the permissions on the executable file to be 'executable'?

Comment: the posted code fails to call `fclose( file );` before exiting.  This bit of sloppiness means the OS has to cleanup the mess.  Much better for the code to cleanup after itself.

Comment: C does not provide a standard way to determine the _current working directory_.  A common compiler specific solution is [getcwd](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getcwd.html).  What compiler are you using?

Comment: @user3629249 I tried chmod +x fileTest and it didn't help. Is there anything else I should be doing?

Comment: regarding: `printf("file failed to open\n");`  Error messages should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` and when the error originates from a system function, (as this one does) much better to call: `perror( "fopen failed" );`  or `fprintf( stderr, "fopen failed to open test.txt for reading because of %s\n", strerror() );  and when a program fails, should handle the error, in this case, by calling `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: @user3629249 added fclose(file), but it does not fix my problem.

Comment: My comments are about 'problems' in the code, not about how to run the executable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the full path of the file `"test.txt"`.

I tested it on the macOS High Sierra 10.13.2 with g++ 5.5.0. This is the output

[image]

Comment: Thought I had tried this. I think I misspelled something in the path. Thanks.

Comment: this has nothing to do with the OPs question of why they cannot run the executable by double clicking it.

Comment: @user3629249; Unfortunately it has to do with it. OP says that when he runs it by clicking the executable then it prints `file failed to open`, that means it doesn't find the file. Giving full path of the file solves this issue. This happens to me also sometimes when I forget to give full path of the file.

Answer (score 0):

the following proposed code:

1. outputs the current working directory path
2. handles any error on the call to `fopen()`
3. outputs a message if the call to `fopen()` is successful
4. handles any error on the call to `getcwd()`

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main( void )
{
    char pathName[1024];

    if( !getcwd( pathName, sizeof( pathName ) )
    {
        perror( "getcwd failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, getcwd successful

    printf( "current working Directory: %s\n", pathName );

    FILE* file =  fopen("test.txt","r");
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        perror("file failed to open\n");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, fopen successful

    printf( "call to fopen successful\n" );
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

However, it does not effect your question about why double clicking the executable does not cause the executable to be executed.